# How can i remove %20 from uri JavaScript when passing two variables

Tags: javascript, php

im trying this code in javascrpit

```
    adminButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const user = this.getAttribute('data-id');
            const id = document.querySelector("body").getAttribute('data-id');

            console.log(typeof(user))
            window.location.href =
                `../utiles/ToggleAdmin.php?id=${id}&user=${encodeURIComponent(user)}`;

        })
```

note that i after i got redirected to this url it shows %20 after user=:
http://localhost/Stock%20inventory%20+%20store/store/utiles/ToggleAdmin.php?id=G43GH&user=%20si35
and the php query dont excute
after i remove %20 manualy from url bar the php query excutes correctly
by the way it shows
**Internal Server Error**

> *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
> wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error
> occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.*

thanks in advance

i tried redirect myself from page to page and passing two variables in url's using javascript
then i found an additional space is in my url
i expect it like **user=J45h5** Not like **user=%20J45h5(user= J45h5)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're encountering an issue with URL encoding when passing variables in a JavaScript redirect. The %20 in the URL represents a space character, which can cause problems when processing the URL on the server side.

To fix this issue, you should make sure that the user variable is properly encoded before appending it to the URL. You can use the encodeURIComponent() function to achieve this. Here's an updated version of your JavaScript code:

```
adminButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const user = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    const id = document.querySelector("body").getAttribute('data-id');

    console.log(typeof(user))
    window.location.href = `../utiles/ToggleAdmin.php
        ?id=${id}&user=${encodeURIComponent(user)}`;
    });
});
```

By using encodeURIComponent(), you ensure that the user variable is properly encoded in the URL, and it should no longer cause issues with spaces or special characters when passed to the server. This should help resolve the Internal Server Error you're encountering.